# div height automatically changing causing error with styling

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with `span` where it is changing the height of my `div`, breaking the styling I have implemented.

I have four images stacked 2 by 2 and I want text to roll up when I hover over them.

However, when I hover over them and the text appears it changes the size of the `div` since I have translated the text up by a certain amount.

I have made the `div`s blue so you can better see what is happening.

The `div`s obtain their height automatically. There are no set pixel heights in my website; everything is made using percentages so it would seem I can't just hide overflow.

Any help would be much appreciated on how I can fix this.

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background-image: url("images/background/space2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
}

#navigation {
  width: 17%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-left: 8%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  float: left;
}

.navigationbody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigationbody a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
}

.navigationbody a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

#navcontent {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50%;
  position: static;
  background-color: ;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#icon {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: ;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

#bodycontainer {
  bottom: 200px;
}

#icon img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#contentcontainer {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#contentcontainer:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#content {
  padding: 0px;
}

.about {
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}

.about a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.about h1 {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}

.about h2 {
  color: white;
}

.abouthome {
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.abouthome h2 {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
}

.abouthome a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.software {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: ;
}

.software img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.software img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#contentgames {
  right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}

.games {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

.games:hover {}

.games span {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  align-content: center;
}

.games:hover span {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Steven game design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css" />
</head>
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="navcontent">
    <div id="icon">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
    <div id="bodycontainer">
      <div class="navigationbody"></div>
      <div class="navigationbody">
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigationbody">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigationbody">
        <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigationbody">
        <a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigationbody">
        <a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigationbody">
        <a href="page6.html">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="contentcontainer">
      <div id="contentgames">

        <div class="games">
          <a href="futurama.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>

          <span> This is a simple game I started making in flash. All of the artwork was created in flash. Unfortunately I never completed the game many things don't work such as the score, taking damage, boss and many more
   </span>

        </div>

        <div class="games">
          <a href="futurama.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>

          <span> This is a simple game I made in flash it took less than a week to create.</span>

        </div>

        <div class="games">
          <a href="futurama.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>

          <span> This is another simple game in flash I made over the course of a few days.</span>

        </div>

        <div class="games">
          <a href="futurama.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>

          <span>This is the game I am currently working on. It is my first 3d game. I am making it in the unreal engine 4.</span>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have `height: auto` on `.games`, you'll need to set that to something else (px, %, etc).

Comment: It has to be auto unfortunately that's the problem as the pictures scale depending on the screen size so that they will always take up the same amount off screen space silly I know but the whole website works on percentages nothing has a pixel size.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're aiming for - see my example in the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is for the image to be the deciding factor for the position and size of the div and the elements within it, this minimal, responsive example should provide some examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/d7aab2x7/2/

The critical code sets the text block to be positioned absolutely, allow the div to constrain it's size around the image:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  transition: bottom 200ms ease-out;
}
```

For this HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  <span>Some text that will appear on hover of the image</span>
</div>
```

Please note: I have re-created using the simplest example possible, and my fiddle uses only CSS for animation. Hopefully this provides you with an answer, while also providing general usefulness to the next person searching for something like this.

Comment: Thank you this has solved the problem sorry I took so long to get back to you I was at work. I really appreciate it I thought for sure there would be no solution.